# too many arguments to append to txt file

Tags: append, global

Inputs are collected in the first function, available in the second function, but I need to be able to append all to the text file.  It says too many arguments, please help!

```
def newMember(): # gathers info to pass into sub routine to write to file
    global surname, year, status, nights, points
    print("Please enter the following information")
    surname=input("Surname\n")
    year=input("Year joined \n")
    status=input("Membership status \n")
    nights=input("Nights booked \n")
    points=input("Points balance \n")
    print("Please confirm these details \nSurname: "+surname+ "\nYear joined: "+year+ "\nMembership status: "+status+"\nNights booked: "+nights+ "\nPoints balance: "+points)
    reply=input("Please type either Yes or No\n")
    if reply in["Y","y","Yes","yes"]: #using an array in the selection to cover possible inputs
        print("Thank you, these will now be written to file.  Returning you to the main menu options") # write to file
        time.sleep(3)
        appendMember()
    elif reply in ["n","N","no","No"]: 
        print("Sorry, you will now be prompted to enter the details again")
        newMember()
    else:
        print("I'm sorry, I didn't quite catch that, the program will now restart")
        newMember()



def appendMember():
    global surname, year, status, nights, points
    with open('SampleData2017.txt', mode="a")as crawdale:
        crawdale.write[surname, year, status, nights, points]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why that didn't paste as code.  It is the last line that is the issue though, one piece of data, such as surname will append, more than one will not

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a single parameter to write file. You could convert the list to comma seperated string like this

```
def appendMember():
    global surname, year, status, nights, points
    with open('SampleData2017.txt', mode="a") as crawdale:
        crawdale.write(",".join([surname, year, status, nights, points]))
```

Comment: oh my gosh, I've been working on that since 9am, thank you so much!

Comment: @A.Teacher Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted